# How to use google maps api 3 heatmap with naturalearthdata

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I have data from natural earth for coordinates country wise. These are array inside arrays inside arrays.

My data ( example for one country)

```
coordinates":
[[[[6818,7133],[6820,7134],[6820,7126],[6817,7128],[6818,7133]]],[[[6819,7322],[6840,7326],[6842,7305],[6869,7285],[6937,7293],
[6923,7319],[6953,7324],[7012,7369],[7032,7360],[7057,7370],[7092,7333],[7074,7306],[7024,7278],[7023,7255],[6996,7195],[6973,7200],
[6969,7150],[6951,7137],[6939,7192],[6922,7167],[6909,7188],[6949,7229],[6935,7237],[6886,7236],[6870,7262],[6829,7277],[6818,7260],
[6843,7237],[6816,7220],[6837,7209],[6832,7189],[6847,7142],[6823,7124],[6820,7141],[6792,7124],[6767,7075],[6740,7073],[6699,7023],
[6646,6986],[6647,6972],[6586,6945],[6580,6925],[6588,6875],[6574,6835],[6574,6783],[6504,6717],[6476,6742],[6454,6807],[6424,6859],
[6410,6911],[6384,6956],[6360,7072],[6367,7093],[6351,7149],[6344,7113],[6310,7098],[6291,7105],[6258,7137],[6287,7155],[6241,7174],
[6227,7195],[6247,7208],[6280,7205],[6313,7222],[6265,7289],[6295,7328],[6337,7325],[6368,7360],[6381,7388],[6416,7427],[6415,7446],
[6438,7461],[6400,7495],[6393,7534],[6410,7548],[6453,7539],[6490,7559],[6513,7572],[6527,7544],[6546,7534],[6542,7507],[6563,7480],
[6530,7473],[6541,7434],[6608,7397],[6589,7383],[6579,7353],[6660,7310],[6714,7305],[6751,7281],[6795,7274],[6820,7286],[6819,7322]]]]
```

Source link: [World data country wise](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js)

```
 heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: getPoints(),
      map: map
    });
```

The getPoints function from sample heatmap example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) looks like

```
function getPoints() {
    return [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
      ...
      ...
     ]
  }
```

So now how do I map this data to my getPoints function in order to provide lat longs conveniently? I am not sure if how to input this data in heatmap object basically!

Comment: Those are not latitudes and longitudes. If they are geographic coordinates, you need to know what projection that are in and do a conversion.  Much easier to use the natural earth data Tha I already in the correct projection.

Comment: I figured the same when I tried adding them manually. I found the geojson for naturalearth. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function (or a similar one) to generate a one-dimensional array of the pairs of coordinates.

```
function recursiveArrayPass(source) {
    if (typeof source != 'object')
        return []

    if (typeof source[0] == 'number') { 
        return [source]
    }

    var result = []
    for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) 
        result = result.concat(recursiveArrayPass(source[i]))

    return result   
}
```

and then use something like this on the resulted array

```
function getPoints(coords_array) {
    var result = []

    for (var i = 0; i < coords_array.length; i++) 
        result.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coords_array[i][0], coords_array[i][1]));

    return result   
}
```

Comment: Diana a sec ago I posted an update. I am not sure if these are lat longs.  I tried adding a few of them manually and heatmap just won't show up for these points